# Query returns SQL error message 537

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

As part of validation of ETL process, I'm currently attempting to replicate existing query which ses a function to strip URL into domain and seperate parts

My query is below:

```
SELECT substring(Referrer , 1, patindex('%?%', Referrer) - 1) as URL
FROM dbo.tableA MRD
JOIN dbo.tableB mm
ON mm.MetId = MRD.MetId
AND mm.MetId = 4
```

Query returns resultset and  errors.

```
Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
```

Still learning SQL, but google search states 'This error is caused by passing a negative value to the length parameter of the SUBSTRING, LEFT and RIGHT string functions'

Is it because I've got empty URL fields and if so, how can I modify the above query to compenstate?

Answer (score 4):

Its probably that some of your Referrer strings don't contain the `?` character.

If there is no match then `PATINDEX` will return 0.

The substring would then be trying to get characters 1 to -1 from the referrer string.

You may need to wrap the statement in a case statement with a second called to `PATINDEX` unless anyone comes up with a nicer workaround:

```
select 
    case patindex('%?%', Referrer)
       when 0 then Referrer
       else substring(Referrer , 1, patindex('%?%', Referrer) - 1) 
    end as URL
from dbo.tableA MRD
    JOIN dbo.tableB mm
      ON mm.MetId = MRD.MetId
        AND mm.MetId = 4
```